# White gap on orientation != portrait flat

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

My UWP App displays a white gap when the mobile device orientation is rotated to left or right.[image]

My XAML:

```
<prismMvvm:SessionStateAwarePage>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="VideoItemsListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <MediaElement x:Name="VideoPlayer" Grid.Row="1">
    </MediaElement>
</Grid>
```

Do I need to implement something to remove the gap? How can I fix this?

Comment: What are showing in the listbox?  I do not see a data template defined

Comment: I edited the xaml code.

Comment: if you change the background color of the listbox does the white patch change color?

Comment: What about some full screen options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the stripe is for status bar. [Hide the status bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar.hideasync) like follows may resolve your issue.

```
public RemoveGap()
{
   this.InitializeComponent(); 
   if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
   {
       StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();  
   }
}
```

Pay attention, to use this class, we need to add a mobile special reference as following picture shows:[image]